# Combine select top 1 SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, union

I have 4 select statements:

```
SELECT top 1 software, auditDate, versionNumber FROM table1 where software = 'software1' order by auditDate desc
SELECT top 1 software, auditDate, versionNumber FROM table1 where software = 'software2' order by auditDate desc
SELECT top 1 software, auditDate, versionNumber FROM table1 where software = 'software3' order by auditDate desc
SELECT top 1 software, auditDate, versionNumber FROM table1 where software = 'software4' order by auditDate desc
```

Currently, each select statement returns a table with one row like this:

```
   software  | auditDate  | versionNumber
1| software1 | 8/22/2017  | 5.0
```

If the `top 1` condition wasn't there, then the result table would have more rows of the same software with different `auditDate` and `versionNumber`, but I only needed the most recent record (`auditDate`) for each software.

*I'd like to roll all these select statements into one query* that returns a table similar to this:

```
   software  | auditDate  | versionNumber
1| software1 | 8/22/2017  | 5.0
2| software2 | 8/20/2017  | 5.3
3| software3 | 8/21/2017  | 4.9
4| software4 | 8/16/2017  | 5.6
```

where each row is the same as the individual `select top 1` statement above.

A `UNION` doesn't seem to work because of the `order by` clause and I'm stumped  for other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another Option is using the **WITH TIES** clause

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       software, auditDate, versionNumber 
 From  table1 
 Where software IN ('software1','software2','software3','software4')
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By software Order By auditDate Desc)
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this right the generic for this is `Top N with ties` and has to be accompanied by an `order by` clause. I'm not understanding the `Partition` part though, could you provide some explanation?

Comment: @CuriousOne This approach does not generate an extra field like the CTE approach.  Row_Number() is a window function, it will generate a sequence of numbers 1 - n  "resetting" for each software, order by the descending date.  If not comfortable with the window functions, it would be well worth your time to experiment.  They can be invaluable !

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not too experienced with SQL but when I begin my deep study of it I will remember to research window functions like this. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY software ORDER BY auditDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.table1
    WHERE software IN ('software1','software2','software3','software4')
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: While this does technically provide the records I need, it produces extra columns from table1 that would mess up my output, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @CuriousOne yup, but, I mean, you know can select the columns you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an id col and don't want to name the software use something like:

Select * from ( (Select id, software, max(auditDate) from table1 group by id, software) a Left join table1 b on a.id = b.id)