# Pick last record from left table when no rows match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having hard time to figure this out, I have 2 tables and I want if no row match in two tables then pick the data from last row of left table. For Example:-

Table 1:-

```
Id     Category
1       Fruits
2       Electronics
```

Table 2:-

```
Id   Item         CategoryId
1    Television       2
2    Camera           2
3    Apple            1
4    foo              3
```

Expected Output:

```
Television      Electronics
Camera          Electronics
Apple           Fruits
foo             Electronics  #No Id match so last record from 1st table
```

If I do left join, it gives me null so was wondering if in the case statement I should again load the first table with data some thing like this:-

```
SELECT B.Item
     , CASE WHEN B.Id IS NULL (--Take max and select table2 again?)
       ELSE B.Category END
FROM Table2 A
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 B
         ON A.CategoryId= BId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is a `Coalesce()` in concert with a `CROSS Join`

**Example**

```
Select A.Item 
      ,Category = coalesce(B.Category,C.Category)
 From  T2 A
 Left Join  T1 B on A.CategoryId= B.Id
 Cross Join (Select Top 1 * From T1 Order by ID desc) C
```

**Returns**

```
Item        Category
Television  Electronics
Camera      Electronics
Apple       Fruits
foo         Electronics
```

> **EDIT - Requested Update**

```
Select A.FoodID
      ,A.BarID
       A.Item 
      ,Category = coalesce(B.Category,C.Category)
 From  @T2 A
 Left Join  @T1 B on A.CategoryId= B.Id
 Cross Apply (
              Select Top 1 Category 
               From  T1 
               Where FoodID = A.FoodID    -- Notice the WHERE
                and  BarID  = A.BarID
                Order by ID Desc
            ) C
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good. I gave a very simple example so this solution works. In reality, in my T1 table I have different columns so I will have to group by all and select top 1?

Comment: @RahulSingh You may not have to group.  Take a peek at TOP 1 WITH TIES  ... example ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821615/combine-select-top-1-sql-statements/45821667#45821667

Comment: @RahulSingh Without seeing your actual data/desired results.  Another option is CROSS APPLY ()

Comment: So I am trying to add a left join on a big query. Table is joined by two conditions like fooId & barId. So for each `fooId` & `barId` I need to pick the balance (for non matching rows take balance of max `barId` for that `foodId`)

Comment: @RahulSingh Seems like a CROSS APPLY may be the best fit here.  Give me a moment and I can take a stab at it for you

Comment: @RahulSingh See EDIT for a sample on how to use a CROSS APPLY

Comment: @RahulSingh Use OUTER APPLY if you don't want to exclude possible NULL values

Comment: Cross Apply is not returning any rows with above query and outer apply is returning null.

Comment: Thanks, was using wrong condition. Awesome solution!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much, I don't see any reason to get cute with it.

```
SELECT B.Item
     , CASE WHEN B.Id IS NULL THEN
         ( SELECT Category,
             FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn,
                           Category
                      FROM Table1
                  ) TMP
            WHERE rn = 1
         )                
       ELSE B.Category END
FROM Table2 A
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 B
         ON A.CategoryId= BId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only one `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.category
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      order by (case when t2.categoryId = t.category then 1 else 2 end),
               id desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Much better ... even serves OP's extended question